# Is it possible to run an Automator workflow when a USB device is connected?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, usb-flash-drive, automator, autorun

I would like to run an Automator workflow every time I connect a certain thumbdrive to my OS X Snow Leopard system.  This workflow will copy certain files from my hard drive onto the thumb drive.  I have the workflow part figured out, but I don't know how to trigger it.  Ideally, I wouldn't need to do anything; it would run as soon as the drive is mounted.

Is this possible?  Am I approaching this from the wrong angle?

The solution only really needs to work on Snow Leopard.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Marco Polo.... http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/

What you are looking to do is detect an attached USB Device...  Which then you can run an shell script, which could activate the automator script, or if you compile the automator script, you could just execute it.